# Install localhost server on windows RT

Tags: xampp, windows-8, wamp, wampserver

I want to install a localhost server on a tablet with windows RT 32 bit.
I tried installing the xampp 32 bit for windows 7 which didn't work.

Is there any (xampp/wamp) server available for Windows RT currently or can I tweak somehow to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: yesterday I've installed wamp server. I didn't test all features but it seems to work fine. I've installed 64bit version

Comment: What's not working? The x86 version should be able to install xampp.

Comment: It displays an error as soon as run the exe saying that the executable is not compatible with this machine. The error is because there is no setup available for ARM architecture which the machine has. Probably I will have to wait.

Comment: On Windows RT? Not very likely... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP is not supported on ARM processors.